# What does adb device status mean?

Tags: android-studio, adb

I am getting the message `adb device status:offline` in my terminal of Android Studio. What does this mean ?
I have one android virtual device as my emulator. My emulator is working fine. And it is also connecting to the internet since maps are getting loaded. So is this gonna affect anything ?

Answer (score 1):

This is described in [the `adb` documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html):

> State — The connection state of the instance may be one of the following:
>
> `offline` — the instance is not connected to adb or is not responding.
>
> `device` — the instance is now connected to the adb server. Note that this state does not imply that the Android system is fully booted and operational, since the instance connects to adb while the system is still booting. However, after boot-up, this is the normal operational state of an emulator/device instance.
>
> `no device` — there is no emulator/device connected.

So if your device is listed as `offline` it might affect your ability to communicate with it via `adb` - e.g. to collect logs. It's not an inidcator of the device's internet connection status.

Answer (score 1):

[The adb documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) says that there are 3 connection states: `offline`, `device`, and `no device`, but there are actually a few more connection states that the device can be in. You can see this in [the adb header file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/adb.h) on line 174.

From the adb documentation:

> - `offline` - the instance is not connected to adb or is not responding.
> - `device` - the instance is now connected to the adb server. Note that this state does not imply that the Android system is fully booted and operational, since the instance connects to adb while the system is still booting. However, after boot-up, this is the normal operational state of an emulator/device instance.
> - `no device` - there is no emulator/device connected.

Some other states:

- `recovery` - Your device is in recovery mode. This mode is used to recover your phone when it is broken or to install custom roms.
- `sideload` - Your device is in sideload mode and can accept `adb sideload` commands. This mode is used to push and flash zip file images to the device and is accessed through recovery mode.
- `unauthorized` - The adb host's RSA public key has not been added to the device. This happens when you haven't clicked allow on the *Allow usb debugging?* dialog on the device.
- `no permissions` - Insufficient permissions to communicate with the device.
- `host` - I haven't found any good explanation of what this state is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not answer my question as to how come my emulator is working fine even though it is showing offline as my adb device status.